# Computing Div and Mod

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I know someone has asked similar question [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626162/algorithm-for-computing-div-and-mod), but my issue is different.

[image]

**Question**: I understand all parts of the algorithm except the case when $r = d-r$ I tried to follow an example but still can not get why this step is done?

Comment: Because if $a$ is negative, the while loop will give you $r= |a| \bmod{d}$, and you want to return $a \bmod{d} = -|a| \bmod{d} = d-r$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $a$ is negative, you drop out of the **while** loop when $|a|=qd+r$ and $0\le r<d$. At this point

$$a=-|a|=-(qd+r)=(-q)d+(-r)\,,$$

where $-d<-r\le 0$. That’s fine if $r=0$: plainly the desired quotient is $-q$, and the desired remainder is $0$. If $r>0$, however, it’s not what we want: when the remainder is not $0$, we want it to be positive and less than $d$. If $-d<-r<0$, and we add $d$ to $-r$ (as in the instruction $r:=d-r$), we’ll get such a number: $-d<-r<0$ implies that $0<d-r<d$. Let $r'=d-r$; then

$$a+d=(-q)d-r+d=(-q)d+r'\,,$$

where $0<r'<d$, so

$$a=(-q)d-d+r'=-(q+1)d+r'\,,$$

where $0<r'<d$, and we have our quotient, $-(q+1)$, and our remainder, $r'$.

Comment: Thank you professor. Could you please add to your answer why time complexity is $\mathcal{O}(q \log a)$ or I should ask that in a separate question?

Comment: @Avra: You’re welcome. It should probably be a separate question, since I’ve worked very little with time complexity. I suspect, though, that the factor of $q$ is because the **while** loop is repeated $q$ times, and the factor of $\log a$ accounts for the time required to perform a subtraction on a number whose length in bits is on the order of $\log a$.

Answer (score 1):

If we will have, for example 13 mod 5, it's equals to 3.
But (-13) mod 5 = 2.

So, if we would have negative number as an input and our remainder is more than zero, we will subtract it from our divisor and receive correct remainder.